# In PHP, are there any advantages to using forward_static_call_array() instead of call_user_func_array() when dynamically calling a static method?

Tags: php, class, methods, static

Specifically, is one more efficient than the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is at leat two differences between [`forward_static_call_array`](http://php.net/forward_static_call_array) and [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) :

- The first one only exists since PHP 5.3
- The first one must be called from inside a class

After that, I suppose there is some difference that's related to Late Static Binding, that was introduced with PHP 5.3.

Actually, if you take a closer look at the given example, it seems to be exactly that : the "context" of the class inside which you are using `forward_static_call_array` is "kept", in the called method.

Considering this portion of code, that's derived from the given example :

```
class A {
    const NAME = 'A';
    public static function test() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        echo static::NAME, " ".join(',', $args)." \n";      // Will echo B
    }
}

class B extends A {
    const NAME = 'B';
    public static function test() {
        echo self::NAME, "\n";          // B
        forward_static_call_array(array('A', 'test'), array('more', 'args'));
    }
}

B::test('foo');
```

You'll get this output :

```
B
B more,args
```

i.e. from the method in class A, you "know", via the `static::` keyword, that you're "coming from B".

Now, if you try to do the the same thing with `call_user_func` :

```
class B extends A {
    const NAME = 'B';
    public static function test() {
        echo self::NAME, "\n";          // B
        call_user_func_array(array('A', 'test'), array('more', 'args'));
    }
}
```

*(the rest of the code doesn't change)*

You'll get this output :

```
B
A more,args
```

Note the **A** on the second line ! With `forward_static_call_array`, you didn't get an **A**, but a **B**.

That's the difference : `forward_static_call_array` forwards the static context to the method that's called, while `call_user_func_array` doesn't.

About your efficiency question : I have no idea -- you'd have to benchmark ; but that's really not the point : the point is that those two functions don't do the same thing.